# Cardinality of union of sets whose intersection is the empty set

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $ n \geq 3 $ an integer such that $\cap_{i=1}^nA_i = \emptyset$.

Prove or disprove: $|\cup_{i=1}^nA_i|=\sum_{i=1}^n|A_i|$

I tried drawing every possible combination of 3 sets to find a counter-proposition, because with what I know about the empty intersection of all 3 sets I can see using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle that :

$|\cup_{i=1}^3A_i|=\sum_{i=1}^3|A_i| - |A_1\cap A_2| -  |A_1\cap A_3|- |A_2\cap A_3| $
However I could not manage to find such an example that would falsify this claim.

I could not manage to prove this either - I know this much be correct when the sets are pairwise disjoint, and this is easily provable, which further strengthens my idea that I have to find a counter proposition.

Thanks in advance for any guidance or tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is completely false, take the following example for n=3

$A_1 = \{x,y\}, A_2= \{y,z\}, A_3= \{x,z\}$

Then $\cap A_i = \phi$, but $\cup A_i = \{x,y,z\}$, so $|\cup A_i| = 3 , \sum |A_i| = 6$

Clearly not equal.

For general n, let $x_i$ be n distinct elements, and take $A_i$ to be all but the $i^{th}$ element, then again one gets a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_1=\{1\}$ and $A_i=\{2\}$ for  $2 \leq i \leq n$. Then $\cap_i A_i$ is empty but $\sum_i |A_i|=n\geq 3 >2=|\cup_i A_i|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ X :=\ \{1 ... n\},\ $ where $\ n\ge 3.\ $

Define:

$$ \forall_{k=1}^n\quad A_k :=\ X\setminus\{k\} $$

Then
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k = \emptyset, $$
and

$$ \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \right| = n\ <
           n\cdot(n-1)\ = \sum_{k=1}^n |A_k| $$

*Great!*

Comment: On my screen (Windows 10 laptop), this is not showing clearly and it is hard to follow.

Comment: I tried to edit it, I hope that I have not changed the meaning.  It appears that your frequent use of backslash space was confusing the rendering.

Comment: badjohn, you're not bad at all. Thank you very much. I was already in the middle of writing my answer without any mathematical symbols but saw that you already took your action. Thank you good @badjohn.

Comment: @badjohn, from now on, I will avoid the extra backslashes. Thank you for your advice. (On the other hand, I like a lot of space and I like my own editing ways. Too bad.)

Comment: I would also like some extra space but I did not know backslash space.  I tried removing it because it was unfamiliar and I found that it appeared to solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Mac+StackEx. I wish I knew what's going on. I get a pdf file on my own Mac which is fine. If you copy my TeX code from my "Answer" here, then you can compile it on your own computer. Perhaps, this is too much trouble. Others could see my previous answers (to other "Questions") fine why I couldn't. I know that some did because they have awarded me with some "reputation" points.

Answer (score 1):

@Sagers gives a good answer in which none of the $A_i$ are empty but the problem does not appear to require that so an even more simple counterexample is $A_1 = \emptyset$ and $A_i = \{1\}$ for $i > 1$.